# Trouble with R and vector length NA values appended

Tags: r, vector

I've looked this over and I can't quite understand why this is giving me NA values appended onto the vector I want. Prompt below:

"The function should return a vector where the first element is the sum of the first `n` elements of the input vector, and the rest of the vector is a copy of the other elements of the input vector.  For example, if the input vector is `(2, 3, 6, 7, 8)` and `n = 2`, then the output should be the vector `(5, 6, 7, 8)`"

```
 testA<- c(1,2,3,4,5)    
myFunction <- function(vector1, n)
       {
       sum1=0
       for(i in 1:n)
         {
          sum1<-sum1+vector1[i]
          newVector<-c(sum1,vector1[n+1:length(vector1)])
         }
       return(newVector)
         }

print(newVector) 
myFunction(testA, 3)
```

Output is: `[1]  6  4  5 NA NA NA` when it should just be `6 4 5`

Answer (score 1):

**There is no need for a `for` loop here;** you can do something like this

```
test <- c(2, 3, 6, 7, 8)

myfunction <- function(x, n) c(sum(x[1:n]), x[-(1:n)])
myfunction(test, 2)
#[1] 5 6 7 8

testA <- c(1,2,3,4,5)   
myfunction(testA, 3)
#[1] 6 4 5
```

Explanation: `sum(x[1:n])` calculates the sum of the first `n` elements of `x` and `x[-(1:n)]` returns `x` with the first `n` elements removed.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `head` and `tail`

```
n <- 2
c(sum(head(test, 2)), tail(test, -2))
#[1] 5 6 7 8
```

#### data

```
test <- c(2, 3, 6, 7, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I try to compare the efficiency of above two functions, which are answer post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52472214/3806250 with the question post.

```
> testA <- 1:5    
> myFunction <- function(vector1, n) {
+        sum1 <- 0
+        for(i in 1:n) {
+           sum1 <- sum1 + vector1[i]
+           newVector <- c(sum1, vector1[n+1:length(vector1)])
+          }
+        newVector <- newVector[!is.na(newVector)]
+        return(newVector)
+        }
> 
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myFunction(testA, 3))
Unit: microseconds
                 expr   min     lq     mean median    uq     max neval
 myFunction(testA, 3) 3.592 4.1055 77.37798  4.106 4.619 7292.85   100
> 
> myfunction <- function(x, n) c(sum(x[1:n]), x[-(1:n)])
> 
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myfunction(testA, 2))
Unit: microseconds
                 expr   min   lq     mean median    uq      max neval
 myfunction(testA, 2) 1.539 1.54 47.04373  2.053 2.053 4462.644   100
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone's answers! I was really tired last night and couldn't come up with this simple solution:

```
    function(vector1, n)
  {
  sum1=0
  for(i in 1:n) #scans input vector from first element to input 'n' element
    {
    sum1<-sum1+vector1[i]#Find sum of numbers scanned 
    newVector<-c(sum1,vector1[n+1:length(vector1)])#new output vector starting with the sum found then concatonates rest of the original vector after 'n' element
    length(newVector)<-(length(newVector)-(n)) #NA values were returned, length needs to be changed with respect to 'n'
  }
  return(newVector)
  print(newVector)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already great solutions, but here is another option which does minimum modifications on you original code:

```
testA<- c(1,2,3,4,5)    
myFunction <- function(vector1, n)
{
  sum1=0
  for(i in 1:n)
  {
    sum1<-sum1+vector1[i]
  }

  newVector<-c(sum1,vector1[(n+1):length(vector1)]) # we take this line out of the for loop
  # and put the n+1 in between parenthesis

  return(newVector)
}
newVector <- myFunction(testA, 3)
print(newVector)
```

The problem on the original code/example was that `n+1:length(vector1)` was supossed to return `[1] 4 5`, in order to do the appropiate subsetting (obtaining the last elements in the vector which weren't included in the sum of the first `n` elements), but it is actually returning `[1] 4 5 6 7 8`. Since there are no elements in positions `6:8` in `testA`, this is the reason why there are appearing missing values/NAs.

What `n+1:length(vector1)` is actually doing is first obtaining the secuence `1:length(vector1)` and then adding `n` to each element. Here is an example of this behaviour using values:

```
3+1:5
#> [1] 4 5 6 7 8
```

We can solve this by putting `n+1` between parenthesis on the original code. In our example using values:

```
(3+1):5
#> [1] 4 5
```

Also, taking the assignment of `newVector` out of the loop improves performance, because the binding between `sum1` and the subsetted vector only needs to be done once the sum of the first `n` elements is completed.